# Is there a single word for "Things to do" in different languages?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a single word or a phrase that means "Things to do / tasks". It can be an English word or phrase, or a neologism: *todolist, thingslist,* etc. Or a word that means "a task or item of work done while travelling".

Comment: What do **you** mean by "things to do"? It's an idiom with special meanings and uses, and it may not mean what you think it means, in various contexts.

Comment: You're looking for an English word that is in a different language?! I don't understand…

Comment: I'm looking for a single word or other words that means "Things to do". It can be in english , it might be synonym. it can be in different language. eg: todolist, thingslist etc

Comment: What @John said. *"Don't ask him to help. He's got things to do"* means you shouldn't bother him because he's too busy to help. But *"Don't ask him to help. He's got an agenda"* means he might go through the motions of helping you, but actually he'd be serving his own ***hidden agenda***.

Comment: Can you tell us where or how you would use such a word or phrase? That would make more transparent how we can help you, or whether we should.

Comment: Ah, so you are related to the Kijan Maharjan whose Twitter account describes him as a product designer! Let's see if anyone answers you with a great idea, but the question will probably be closed because help with naming products, companies, etc., are off-topic for this site. Good luck!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your comment illustrates that ***agenda*** has acquired a modern idiomatic meaning. When someone *has an agenda*, it does not always mean they have a typed list of topics for a meeting. It nowadays tends to mean that they have an undisclosed plan of their own,  which is governing their expressions and actions.

Answer (score 7):

***Agenda*** (Latin gerundive - neuter plural of *agendum*) - ***things which are to be done***.

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to "things to do" without any particular direction, like a list of fun things to do while on vacation in Italy,

> **Activity** n. Something done for pleasure or entertainment, especially one involving movement or an excursion.

from [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/activity).

You could also be referring to things which require completion. In that case,

> **Task** n. 1) A piece of work done as part of one’s duties. 2) A difficult or tedious undertaking.

also from [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/task).

Answer (score -1):

Schedule.  Careful with agenda.  Agenda is often associated with nefarious activity or unstated/hidden purpose (particularly in politics).  In a business meeting the use of agenda is clear. Elsewhere?  I'm not so sure.